# How can I resolve this selenium stale reference error when scraping page 2 of a website?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium to scrape Linkedin for jobs but I'm getting the stale reference error.

I've tried refresh, wait, webdriverwait, a try catch block.

It always fails on page 2.

I'm aware it could be a DOM issue and have run through a few of the answers to that but none of them seem to work for me.

```
    def scroll_to(self, job_list_item):
        """Just a function that will scroll to the list item in the column 
        """
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", job_list_item)
        job_list_item.click()
        time.sleep(self.delay)
    
    def get_position_data(self, job):
        """Gets the position data for a posting.
        Parameters
        ----------
        job : Selenium webelement
        Returns
        -------
        list of strings : [position, company, location, details]
        """
        # This is where the error is!
        [position, company, location] = job.text.split('\n')[:3]
        details = self.driver.find_element_by_id("job-details").text
        return [position, company, location, details]

    def wait_for_element_ready(self, by, text):
        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((by, text)))
        except TimeoutException:
            logging.debug("wait_for_element_ready TimeoutException")
            pass

        logging.info("Begin linkedin keyword search")
        self.search_linkedin(keywords, location)
        self.wait()

        # scrape pages,only do first 8 pages since after that the data isn't 
        # well suited for me anyways:  
        
        for page in range(2, 3):
            jobs = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("occludable-update")
            #jobs = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".occludable-update.ember-view")
            #WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'occludable-update')))
            for job in jobs:
                self.scroll_to(job)
                #job.click
                [position, company, location, details] = self.get_position_data(job)
                # do something with the data...
                data = (position, company, location, details)
                #logging.info(f"Added to DB: {position}, {company}, {location}")
                writer.writerow(data)
            # go to next page:
            bot.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//button[@aria-label='Page {page}']").click()
            bot.wait()
        logging.info("Done scraping.")
        logging.info("Closing DB connection.")
        f.close()
        bot.close_session()
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that when `job_list_item.click()` is performed the page is loaded, in this case since you are looping `jobs` which is a list of `WebDriverElement` will become stale. You are returning back to the page but your `jobs` is already stale.

Usually to prevent a stale element, I always prevent the use of the element in a loop or store an element to a variable, especially if the element may change.

Comment: jobs = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("occludable-update") is in the first for loop along with the click next page button so I don't understand how it can be stale. Page 2 is clicked. The element is loaded and it scrolls to that job. It just fails when it clicks it.

Comment: once `self.scroll_to(job)` performed the click and page is reloaded all your elements that are previously stored in a variable will be stale. `self.get_position_data(job)` you are using the job here which is already a stale element.

If page is not loaded after `self.scroll_to(job)`  then the job element clicked might be modified by the page after clicked.

Comment: It works on the first page though. Do you know what I need to do to fix it? Thanks.